# Rails: reading hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a hash data in my controller:

```
 "accept"=>["{:id=>\"12f310f1d9b8f\",
:first_name=>\"San\",
:last_name=>\"Jori\",
 :name=>\"Jori,Santosh\",
 :email=>\"san.jori@west.com\",
 :gender=>nil,
:birthday=>nil,
:profile_picture=>nil,
:relation=>nil}"],
```

But I am not able to read it.

I am trying to read it this way:

```
  if params[:accept].present?
   params[:accept].each do |customer|
   @customer = current_user.customers.new(:name => customer[:name], :email => customer[:email])
   end
  end
```

But it gives error:

```
  no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

Ant anybody help? Please.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the hash name is `accept` not `customer` in your example. Is that an extract from a larger variable? Is it the params hash?

Secondly it's an array of hashes, so you need to get a hash result set out of the array to use. How are you doing so? What is the customer object in your example? This is probably the cause of your error, you're trying to access a hash style key but you're doing that to an array, which would need an int key to access a specific member like so: `customer = accept[0] # the first hash in the array` or inline assuming `customer` == `accept`:

```
@customer = current_user.customers.new(:name => customer[0][:name], :email => customer[0][:email])
```

That said, if all of the hashes keys are matches with the customer object attributes then you can just pass the hash straight in to the `customers.new` method:

```
@customer = current_user.customers.new(accept)
```

This is quite often done in controller `create` actions like so:

```
def create
  @customer = Customer.new(params[:customer])
  ...
end
```

Comment: Hey, yes accept is an array of hash and I wanna read values in each hash. It contains many parameters out of which i need "name" and "email". So i can't pass  new(accept)  or new(params[:customer])

Comment: Is there any way to run this in loop: :name => customer[0][:name], :email => customer[0][:email]. I have updated the question with loop i am using.

Comment: Post the full params that comes through, the extract in your example has the hash contained in quotes, which would make it a string... output the class name of the `accept` object in your code and tell me the result `puts params[:accept].class` and `puts params[:accept][0].class`

Comment: Hey, i tried this in view : <%= params[:accept].class.inspect %> ><%= params[:accept][0].class.inspect %> but it is giving nil. Can u tell where to put it?

Comment: i got this: o/p of params[:accept] is ---- "{:id=>\"base/112f310f1d9b8f\", :first_name=>\"San\",:last_name=>\"Jori\",:name=>\"Jori,San\",:email=>san.jori@west.com\",:gender=>nil,:birthday=>nil,:profile_picture=>nil,:relation=>nil}"{:id=>\"2293b58ce3aa28\",:first_name=>\"Yog\",:last_name=>Shel\",:name=>\"Yog Shel\",:email=>\"yog.shel99@gmail.com\",:gender=>nil,:birthday=>nil,:profile_picture=>nil, :relation=>nil}"

Comment: and o/p of  params[:accept][0] is {:id=>"12f310f1d9b8f", :first_name=>"San", :last_name=>"Jori", :name=>"Jori, San", :email=>"san.jori@west.com", :gender=>nil, :birthday=>nil, :profile_picture=>nil, :relation=>nil}